# How do I switch from Rails 2.3.16 to Rails 4.0.0 in a folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently made a Rails 4 app. Now I am trying to make another.

I made a new folder for the new Rails 4 app. I can't do `rails new myapp` because the rails version is 2.3.16. `ruby -v` is `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]`. `gem install rails` didn't fix it. It installed 4.0.0 but the version in the folder didn't change.

```
rails -v
Rails 2.3.16
```

The version in the existing Rails 4 app is:

```
rails -v
Rails 4.0.0
```

I can't find any documentation or answers for what to do. I don't know how I didn't have this problem when I made the first Rails 4 application.

Comment: Go take a look to RVM: https://rvm.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have 2 Ruby environments installed on your system.

Try running `bundle update rails` in the new folder before creating an app.

If it still doesn't work try setting the rails version to use manually:

```
rvm use ruby-2.0.0@Rails4.0_myapp --create
rvm gemset list
```

If it's still Rails 2.3.16 go to your Gemfile and change

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
```

to

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.0'
```

than
`bundle install`

--

To fix `Rails is not currently installed on this system.` try running

`source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

Comment: I did `rvm use ruby-2.0.0`, and it said to do this: `rvm ruby-2.0.0-p247 do rvm gemset create Rails4.0`. I did that, and then `rvm use ruby-2.0.0`. Now `rails -v` gives me `Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type: $ sudo gem install rails`. I did that, and `rails -v` still gives the same error. I don't have an application, so I copied just the Gemfile from the Rails 4 app I made, and did bundle install. Installing the Rails 4 broke something. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I did a bundle update in the new application folder, and suddenly `rails -v` is 4.0.0. The ~ home directory still gives `Rails is not currently installed on this system.` I was able to make the application, but something is definitely wrong.

Comment: @Eric Updated answer, try to load rvm in current terminal session